# Comparing string array to a character array

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] dictionaryArr= new String[]{"mee","go","bat","me","eat","goal","boy","run","go"};

char[] characterArr={'e','o','b','a','m','g','l'};
```

OR

```
String[] characterArr= new String[]{"e","o","b","a","m","g","l"};
```

I want to compare dictionaryArr to characterArr in such a way that it will

**output: go, me, goal**

**Note: it did'nt output "mee" because letter "e" is repeated and there is only one 'e' in characterArr also it shouldn't print "go" twice**

Here's what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryArr.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < characterArr.length ; j++) {
        if (dictionaryArr[i] == characterArr[j]) {
            System.out.println(dictionaryArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? It's very unlikely there is a method already written somewhere that does exactly what you want.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryArr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < characterArr.length ; j++) {
                if (dictionaryArr[i] == characterArr[j]) {
                    System.out.println(dictionaryArr[i]);
                }
            }
        }`


I am new to this

Comment: Shouldn't it print "go" twice?

Comment: no it shouldn't

Comment: So to sum it up: Each word can only use characters present in the `characterArr`. If a character in the `characterArr` matchets it can not be used again for this word. The result shouldn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the word as soon as you find a matching letter. What you need to do is print it only after there are *no missing letters*. One way to do that is to create a list and check and remove each character as you iterate:

```
private static boolean matches(String word, String[] characterArr) {
    List<String> chars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(characterArr));
    for (String c : word.split("")) {
        if (!chars.remove(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We can call this in a distinct stream to easily avoid duplicate words:

```
Arrays.stream(dictionaryArr)
        .distinct()
        .filter(word -> matches(word, characterArr))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/GdvPAD)

Comment: Any suggestions for me to improve myself more in java? 

Answer (score 0):

shmosel has already given a pretty god answer using `Stream`. Here is a more oldschool solution.

```
List<String> filteredDictionary = new ArrayList<>();
for (String entry: dictionaryArr) {
    // Create a editable collection that contains a copy of the values of characterArr
    List<String> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char c : characterArr) {
        characters.add(c + "");
    }
    boolean print = true;
    for (char c : entry.toCharArray()) {
        // If the character isn't in the characters list characters.remove returns false
        if (!characters.remove(c + "")) {
            print = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Check for duplicates with contains.
    if (print && !filteredDictionary.contains(entry)) {
        filteredDictionary.add(entry);
    }
}
filteredDictionary.forEach(System.out::println);
```